# Angular 2 Routes not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement basic routes with parameters, imitating the Heroes sample (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). My AppModule declares a path:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '',        component: AllStuffComponent },
   { path: 'stuff/:id', component: SingleStuffComponent },
];
```

My SingleStuffComponent looks as follows, just to test out the mechanics:

```
export class SingleGuiComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => params['id'])
      .subscribe((id: any) => console.info("ID=" + id));
  }
}
```

I tried doing a URL in the browser of `http://localhost:3000/stuff/2345`. But in the debugger, I'm seeing:

```
ID=2
ID=3
ID=4
ID=5
```

Why is this happening? I expected just the single console log of `ID=2345`.

Comment: Did you try removing the `switchMap` function, and getting the `params['id']` inside the `subscribe` function?
I suspect the `switchMap` splits up the string to single characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try and only use the map() function to extract the ID and it will work.

```
this.route.params
        .map((params: Params) => params['id'])
        .subscribe((id: any) => console.info("ID=" + id));
```

You will mainly  use switchMap() to get the emitted ID from the map() and use it for a new API call or something like that, so that you won't have to nest 2 subscribe functions.

Example:

```
this.route.params
        .map((params: Params) => params['id'])
        .switchMap(id => this._someService.getSomething(id))
        .subscribe((result: any) => {
           console.log(result);
        });
```

Without switchMap(), you would have to do:

```
this.route.params
  .map((params: Params) => params['id'])
  .subscribe((id) => {
    this._someService
      .getSomething(id)
      .subscribe(result => this.result = result);
  });
```

Comment: Yep! That worked. Although, I'm confused as to why Angular's Hero example (hero-details.component.ts) has switchMap().